# How can I speed up this (relatively simple) query

Tags: mysql

I have a relatively simple query, that simply sums all of the paypal payments my site has accepted, converting them all to GBP using a table of currency conversions which gets updated every day.

```
SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross * IF(PPI.mc_currency='GBP', 1, CC.fConv))

FROM paypal_payment_info PPI

JOIN currency_conversions CC ON CC.sFrom = PPI.mc_currency AND CC.tConv = DATE(PPI.tIPN)
```

with 30,000 rows in PPI and 5,000 in CC the query takes ~9 seconds, on a powerful box.

EXPLAIN shows this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows Extra
1   SIMPLE  PPI ALL                 31271   
1   SIMPLE  CC  ref sFrom   sFrom   9   db.PPI.mc_currency  1167    Using where
```

I've tried an index on `tIPN & mc_currency`, and an index on `mc_currency & tIPN`.  Neither helped.  I thought maybe the `DATE()` function was the problem, so created a column `tIPNdate` and amended the relevant indexes to use that instead, and it didn't make any difference.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: This is joining two complete tables. Why do you expect it to be fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nine seconds isn't an extreme performance problem for this much data.

That being said, it might make sense to break this down into two different `SUM()` operations.

First, do your query for GBP transactions.

```
SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross)
  FROM paypal_payment_info PPI
 WHERE PPI.mc_currency = 'GBP'
```

A compound index on `(mc_currency, mc_gross)` will make that query as fast as it can be. This gets you, probably, the majority of your transactions without needing any join. Hopefully faster.

Then, handle the non-GBP transactions.

```
SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross * CC.fConv)
  FROM paypal_payment_info PPI
  JOIN currency_conversions CC ON CC.sFrom = PPI.mc_currency 
                             AND CC.tConv = DATE(PPI.tIPN)
 WHERE PPI.mc_currency <> 'GBP'
```

To clear up the unsargable `DATE()` part of your JOIN, do this:

```
SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross * CC.fConv)
  FROM paypal_payment_info PPI
  JOIN currency_conversions CC ON PPI.mc_currency = CC.sFrom
                              AND PPI.tPN >= CC.tConv
                              AND PPI.tPN <  CC.tConv + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 WHERE PPI.mc_currency <> 'GBP'
```

Without being sure, I think a compound index on `paypal_payment_info( tPN, mc_currency, mc_gross)` will help this query.  And I think an index on `currency_conversions (sFrom, tConv, fConv)` will also help.

You can then add the results of the two queries with a UNION ALL and another SUM.

```
SELECT SUM(sums) sums
  FROM (
              SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross) sums
                FROM paypal_payment_info PPI
               WHERE PPI.mc_currency = 'GBP'
      UNION ALL
              SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross * CC.fConv) sums
                FROM paypal_payment_info PPI
                JOIN currency_conversions CC ON PPI.mc_currency = CC.sFrom
                                            AND PPI.tPN >= CC.tConv
                                            AND PPI.tPN <  CC.tConv + INTERVAL 1 DAY
               WHERE PPI.mc_currency <> 'GBP'
       ) s
```

Comment: That does bring it down to 3.5 seconds or so, but since it's a very simple sum/product on a relatively small number of rows I still feel it should be a lot quicker, near instant really.  Maybe I'll have to give up and store the currency conversion in the PPI table alongside each transaction.

Comment: Try these indexes: paypal_payment_info(mc_currency, mc_gross, tIPN),
currency_conversions(tConv, sFrom, fConv)

Comment: Actually, try that on your original query first, and see how it performs. Not sure I understand the "to clear up the unsargable ..." part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would simplify the `select` expression by adding a row to your currency conversion table for a rate of `1.00` for `GBP` converting to itself.

Next, reinstate your `tIPNdate` column (having a value of `DATE(PPI.tIPN)`) - that will definitely help.

You need an index on `currency_conversions`:

```
create index index_cc_001 on currency_conversions(tconv, sFrom, fConv);
```

which will have the greatest impact to your query. Also, the order of the columns in the index is important - always put the most varying and exactly matched columns first.

And create an index on `paypal_payment_info`:

```
create index index_ppi_001 on paypal_payment_info(tIPNdate, mc_currency, mc_gross);
```

Both of these indexes are *covering* indexes, meaning all the data needed for the query can be found in the index, thus avoiding the need to access the table.

The query should look like (after removing redundant parts):

```
SELECT SUM(mc_gross * fConv)
FROM paypal_payment_info
JOIN currency_conversions ON sFrom = mc_currency
    AND tConv = tIPNdate
```

Finally, you may find that reversing the order of the tables works better:

```
SELECT SUM(mc_gross * fConv)
FROM currency_conversions
JOIN paypal_payment_info ON sFrom = mc_currency
    AND tConv = tIPNdate
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but while you were typing it out I was busy changing my schema so that I store the currency conversion in the PPI table alongside each transaction.  0.05 seconds now.  Maybe I could have fixed the original query, but this seemed simple, straightforward, and easily maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(PPI.mc_gross * IF(PPI.mc_currency='GBP', 1, CC.fConv))

FROM paypal_payment_info PPI

JOIN currency_conversions CC ON CC.sFrom = PPI.mc_currency AND CC.tConv = DATE(PPI.tIPN) FORCE INDEX (tIPN,mc_currency)
```

Comment: Can you *edit* this post and explain how this code makes the SQL faster? Code only answers are not always too helpful...

Comment: ...Especially as OP states in the question they've already tried to index on `tIPN` and `mc_currency`